# What to do?! Upgrading from 12.10 to 13.04 failed :(

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, 13.04, partial-upgrade

I got an update reminder to go from 12.10 to 13.04.
I followed the instructions, was able to download the package, and started installing.
Up to a point where my computer (seemed to) restart and there was just a black screen (with the backlight on) for more than an hour.
Then I decided that this was too long for an installation and forced my laptop to shut down.
I think that messed it up.

Now I'm stuck in what seems to be 13.04 with bits of 12.10 in it. I tried to upgrade again through software updater but it goes to Partial Upgrade. But when I try that, I get this error message:

```
"An upgrade from 'raring' to 'quantal' is not supported by this tool."
```

Help! What should I do!

I'm running my Ubuntu on my Dell Inspiron.

Answer (score 4):

Failed upgrades often lead to broken package systems.

Run the following commands in a terminal:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

That should fix any package problems you are having, if that doesn't work then please post the output.

I would definitely run these commands to see if it will fix it before considering a fresh re-install. Though if these commands do not fix your problem then a re-install is the way you might have to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running :

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   sudo apt-get install -f

and post any error messages.

If all else fails, it is highly likely a fresh install + restore from backup is goin gto be faster.

Note: A fresh install will NOT over write your data in /home (in theory).

> Since Hardy it is possible to reinstall Ubuntu without losing the content of the /home folder (the folder that contains program settings, internet bookmarks, emails and all your documents, music, videos and other user files). This can be done even if /home is not on a separate partition.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

Comment: It's not 'fresh install' as I know. It's 'reinstalling', means 'repairing' generally. Anyway it's good option to check this out using Live-CD or Live-USB. And that's what I would recommend You. You should easily find this option in system installing dialogue while choosing where to install Ubuntu or something like that.  It's also good to create backup copy while in Live session - You can use default tool called Déjà Dup.

Comment: Thank you will try this during the weekend and report what happens

Answer (score 0):

I expect all your user-generated documents, photos, music and stuff in your home folder is intact. What I would do is use a different computer download 13.04 and create a bootable DVD or USB. Boot from that, and copy everything from your original home directory to a USB drive. (You should have done this before a system upgrade anyway.) Make sure you've really saved everything, including hidden directories. Then do a complete re-install of 13.04, and then copy your data back from the USB drive to your new home directory. You might have to change the permissions afterwards.

*I'd wait a little while, just in case somebody else comes along and points out a flaw in my advise.*

Comment: Yes, I'll try that. I've done USB installs using Win XP, 7 and Quantal before.

Answer (score -2):

boot up using usb and latest version. once in, do an install by double click/clicking icon for upgrade. then it will tel you there already is a version. then choose upgrade. bam

Comment: This is rather sloppy and short for an answer.